# How to select members of a special kind of relationship in sql

Tags: sql, select, relationship

I have 3 table as follow :

```
s(s# int,sname nchar(10))
p(p# int,pname nchar(10))
sp(s# int,p# int)
```

table "s" is table of suppliers and "s#" is primary key of it.also table "p" is table of products and "p#" is primary key on it."s#" and "p#" are foreign key in table "sp".
now my question is "How can I select name of suppliers from table "s" which producing all of products in table "p"...

Comment: Just check I understand this correctly, you want to find the entries in S, where through the join table they match to all entries in P?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT p.*, s.sname FROM s, sp, p WHERE s.s# = sp.s# AND sp.p# = p.p#;
```

This statement will output all products with all their suppliers.
Now we group my suppliers, and count how many products they provide:

```
SELECT s.sname, count(*) FROM s, sp, p WHERE s.s# = sp.s# AND sp.p# = p.p# GROUP BY s.s#;
```

Now we know exacly, how many products each supplier provides. And we also know, how many products are in the productstable:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM p;
```

If you compare these values, you get your desired result:

```
SELECT amounts.name FROM
    (   SELECT s.sname AS name, count(*) AS offers
        FROM s, sp, p 
        WHERE s.s# = sp.s# AND sp.p# = p.p# 
        GROUP BY s.s# ) amounts,     -- this is a temp. tablename
    (   SELECT count(*) AS avaiable FROM p    ) countTbl
    WHERE amounts.offers = countTbl.avaiable;
```

Notice, that I didn't test the query. But you should get an idea on how to solve this problem.

It might also be possible to write this query more efficient, but this one can be understood easily.

Comment: If you only want the suppliers and the products they supply, the first query is what you want.

Comment: If not, please provide an output-example of what you wanna achieve

Comment: at "what is amounts.name": I have an inner select-statement, which produces a new, temporary table. The table-columns are called `name` and `offers`. The table is called `amounts`. (You can change all names if you want)

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to do this, the first I thought of was to invert the logic.

Rather than attempting to find every entry of P let's just look for any that don't exist, then exclude those entries from S:

```
SELECT *
FROM S
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT *
      FROM P
      LEFT JOIN SP
      ON P.P# = SP.P#
         AND SP.S# = S.S#
      WHERE
          SP.P# IS NULL
)
```

Comment: That's a really nice and efficient solution :)

Comment: @maja thanks, your solution isn't exactly going to be slow though, with the right indexs your solution is only going to touch the rows to  evaluate the temporary table of your subqueries.